# Remove Underline from HyperlinkButton in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-10-mobile

---

I need to remove the underline in the content of `HyperLinkButton`.
`TextDecorations` does not exist in this XAML element.

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="BtnTeste"
                Width="100" Height="50" BorderThickness="1" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Foreground="Black" Background="#ffffff"
                NavigateUri="www.google.com"
                Content="Execute" />
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This *underline* is not exposed inside the `HyperlinkButton` *style*. Fortunately, you can easily override its `ContentTemplate` to get rid of it.

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="my link">
    <HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Comment: Great. Work. 
Thanks very much! Greetings

Comment: Your welcome. Please consider accepting it as the answer! :)

Answer (score 11):

Just make like this:

```
<HyperlinkButton>
   <TextBlock Text="Blahblah" />
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the appearance of the button you have to apply a different template. The default template can be found in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296242(v=vs.95).aspx). To remove the underline you have to change the TextDecoration property of the "UnderlineTextBlock" in the template from "Underline" to "None".

```
<Style TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF73A9D8" />
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
  <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
              <Grid Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                  <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="UnderlineTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                              <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="UnderlineTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                              <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                              <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                  </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  <TextBlock
                      x:Name="UnderlineTextBlock"
                      Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      TextDecorations="Underline"
                      Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                  <TextBlock Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                      x:Name="DisabledOverlay"
                      Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      Foreground="#FFAAAAAA"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                  <ContentPresenter 
                      x:Name="contentPresenter"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                  <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

You can apply the template by declaring it as a resource of your page and referencing it from your button.

Declaring a new style:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoUnderlineHyperlinkButtonStyle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
        <!--template from above here-->
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Referencing it:

```
<HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource NoUnderlineHyperlinkButtonStyle}">No Underline!</HyperlinkButton>
```

Comment: Normally I would agree to this, but the dude is working with win10/UWP and your example is a silverlight template. The win10 [style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Mt299132.aspx) is a bit different and that additional object providing the underline doesn't exist. I'm not sure that default style from the docs is correct either since all I see in there is a ContentPresenter, I'd be curious to see what the actual template is if the OP just Right-Clicked->Edit Template so we could see the source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

**Use style**:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="link" Style="{ThemeResource TextBlockButtonStyle}"/>
```